# Json Schema which has at least one of any properties (or more) with ajv

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I am trying to build a simple Json schema (at least that's what I thought) which contains two properties `foo` and `bar`.

It should validate when:

- `foo` is in the json and no other properties
- or `bar` is in the json and no other properties
- or `foo` and `bar` are in the json and no other properties.

I am using [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv) and Typescript and this is the code:

```
interface MyData {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

const schema: JSONSchemaType<MyData> = {
  type: 'object',
  minProperties: 1,
  properties: {
    foo: { type: 'integer' },
    bar: { type: 'string' },
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
};
```

However Typescript forces me to add a `required` field, and if I do, it works but this means that at least one *specific* property is always required which is not what I want. I am not sure if this my wrong understanding of JsonSchema or if this is a Typescript implementation issue of ajv.

Comment: This is an ajv bug. It should not be requiring that you provide the `required` property.

Comment: Sadly they do not consider it a bug. "strict mode" enabled by default requires `required`, or throws an error.

Comment: well since its possible to add a require field with an empty array, thats fine with me I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is just too obvious but I will still post it here if someone else gets also stuck.

I just added an empty `required` property like so:

```
require:[]
```

For some reason I did not think this is allowed, but it works...